# Resteasy mapping @PathParam and @QueryParam to Pojo

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, restful-architecture

I want to reduce my lines of code in a restful ws. My service is :

```
@GET
    @Path("/acc_bloq/{unit}/{id}/search")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public FiltroBean getAcc_Bloq(@PathParam("unit") String unit,
           @PathParam("id") int id, @QueryParam("init") int init, @QueryParam("end") int end){}
```

Is there any way to mapping directly the parameters to a POJO?  so to save lines of code

```
Filter filter = new Filter()
filter.set....
filter.set...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [@BeanParam](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) is what you are looking for.

> The annotation that may be used to inject custom JAX-RS "parameter aggregator" value object into a resource class field, property or resource method parameter.